# How to change "start condition" outside of actions in flex/lex?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

As the title states, how do I change the currently active start condition or state in (f)lex outside of action code? Flex manual states that special directives like `BEGIN` can only be used inside an action.

I am trying to introduce different "modes" in my scanner which change what is returned, these modes are set externally and not in action code so I can't use `BEGIN`.

Any advice? Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (only) use `BEGIN` in the lex.l file, but you can use it anywhere the .l file.  In particular, you can use it in the third section (after the second `%%`), where you can have any C code.  So you can define a function that uses `BEGIN` to set a start state, and then declare that function in a header file and use it anywhere.

example:

```
%s STATE1

%%

<STATE1>"foo"    /* rule applies in state 1 */  ;

%%

void set_state1() {
    BEGIN STATE1;
}
```

add `extern void set_state1();` to a header file and you can call it from anywhere.